# Updating XML files using Python script

Tags: python

I have one XML file `data.xml` as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<player
    name="Michael"
    id = 101
    sal=1001
    mgr="clarke" />
<player
    name="Ricky"
    id = 102
    sal=1002
    mgr="Ponting" />
<player
    name="Shane"
    id = 103
    sal=1003
    mgr="Warne" />
<player
    name="Watson"
    id = 104
    dept="Batsman"
    sal=1004
    mgr="Shane" />
<player
    name="Nathon"
    id = 105
    dept="Bowler"
    sal=1005
    mgr="Lyon" />
</data>
```

How can I:

- update all the emps who do not have `dept` attribute with `dept = "Batsman"`
- Update all the emps with a default `dept = "cricketers"`
- Update selected emps (selected emps will be in another `players.txt`
  files) with `dept = "Cricketers"`

`players.txt` will be a plain text file with only names of players, like:

```
Michael
Ricky
Shane
Watson
```

Comment: You can use [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to read/write/modify XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Using [minidom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) should be enough,
but first, the format of the xml is not correct though since the [attributes must be quoted](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp)

anyway, having that fixed you just need to parse the xml

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('data.xml')
```

And then each of the 3 tasks, which are slightly different, having in common checking player tags within the xml and cheking also for this tags their attributes.

so,

> update all the emps who do not have dept attribute with dept =
>   "Batsman"

Just checking the `"dept"` attribute for all players, setting the ones that throw `KeyValue` exceptions as the dict parsed from the xml doesn't have that key:

```
for p in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("player"):
    try:
        p.attributes["dept"]
    except KeyError:
        p.attributes["dept"] = "Batsman"
```

> Update all the emps with a default dept = "cricketers"

Same as the previous but applying for all players

```
for p in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("player"):
    p.attributes["dept"] = "cricketers"
```

> Update selected emps (selected emps will be in another players.txt
>   files) with dept = "Cricketers"

For this one maybe first load into a list each of the lines of the file

```
p_names = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("players.txt")]
```

And then, same as before, but checking that the attribute name value appears in the preloaded list.

```
for p in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("player"):
    if p.attributes["name"].value in p_names:
        p.attributes["dept"] = "Cricketers"
```